# Different results from scipy.stats.spearmanr depending on how data is produced

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm having some weird problem using spearmanr from scipy.stats. I'm using the values of a polynomial to get some correlations that are a bit more interesting to work with, but if I manually enter the values (as a list, converted to a numpy array) I get a different correlation to what I get if I calculate the values using a function. The code below should demonstrate what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import spearmanr    
data = np.array([  0.4,   1.2,   1. ,   0.4,   0. ,   0.4,   2.2,   6. ,  12.4,  22. ])
axis = np.arange(0, 10, dtype=np.float64)

print(spearmanr(axis, data))# gives a correlation of 0.693...

# Use this polynomial
poly = lambda x:  0.1*(x - 3.0)**3 + 0.1*(x - 1.0)**2 - x + 3.0

data2 = poly(axis)
print(data2) # It is the same as data

print(spearmanr(axis, data2))# gives a correlation of 0.729...
```

I did notice that the arrays are subtly different (i.e. `data - data2` is not exactly zero for all elements), but the difference is tiny - order of 1e-16.

Is such a tiny difference enough to throw off spearmanr by this much?

Answer (score 1):

> Is such a tiny difference enough to throw off spearmanr by this much?

Yes, because Spearman's *r* is based on the sample rank. Such tiny differences can change the rank of values that would otherwise be equal:

```
sp.stats.rankdata(data)
# array([  3.,   6.,   5.,   3.,   1.,   3.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.])
# Note that all three values of 0.4 get the same rank 3.

sp.stats.rankdata(data2)
# array([  2.5,   6. ,   5. ,   2.5,   1. ,   4. ,   7. ,   8. ,   9. ,  10. ])
# Note that two values 0.4 get the rank 2.5 and one gets 4.
```

If you add a small gradient (larger than the numerical difference you observe) to break such ties, you will get the same result:

```
print(spearmanr(axis, data + np.arange(10)*1e-12))
# SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.74545454545454537, pvalue=0.013330146315440047)

print(spearmanr(axis, data2 + np.arange(10)*1e-12))
# SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.74545454545454537, pvalue=0.013330146315440047)
```

This, however, will break any ties that may be intentional and can lead to over- or underestimating the correlation. [`numpy.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) may be the preferable solution if the data is expected to have discrete values.